# не получается объединить датафреймы

Tags: python, pandas, анализ-данных

В двух датафреймах есть идентичные, user_id, по которым и нужно соотнести два датафрейма чтобы они "слились" в один. В первом случае с `df_1` все получилось...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

код с `df_2`

```
    df_2 = df_p_CG2.merge(df_CG2, how='inner')
    df_2
```

получаем на выходе:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в чем проблема? почему выводится только название столбов без строк?

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Насколько я помню, `merge` объединяет по индексам. Возможно, у вас разные индексы в датафреймах. Попробуйте тогда `join` или `concat`, зависит от задачи. Если просто состыковать, то `concat`, а если по значению какой-то колонки, то `join`.

Comment: В двух датафреймах есть идентичные, user_id, по которым и нужно соотнести два датафрейма чтобы они "слились" в один

Comment: Воспроизводимые примеры - в вопрос.

Comment: что не так? указал же код, прикрепил скриншот, что получаем на выходе, мне нужен фрейм с строками, а получил только с столбцами..

Comment: Не даром просят ВОСПРОИЗВОДИМЫЙ пример. В вашем коде вы сначала работает с датафреймами df_p_CG1 и df_CG1, а потом с df_p_CG2 и df_CG2 Что в самих датафреймах вы показывать не желаете и вопрос звучит так "беру РАЗНЫЕ данные, произвожу над ними одни и те-же действия, почему у меня разные результаты"? Один из вариантов ответа  -  потому что во втором случае  идентичных user_id в фреймах не было.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте непосредственное указание столбцов, по которым будет объединение.

```
df_2 = df_p_CG2.merge(df_CG2, left_on='user_id', right_on='user_id', how='inner')
```

Если не сработает, то нужно смотреть какие значения в остальных фреймах.

Comment: Не сработало, тоже самое... строк нет..

Comment: Если уверены в данных, то видимо датафрейм где-то перезаписался. Лучше перезапустить все ячейки сначала. А ещё лучше давать новые имена переменных при каждом изменении датафрейма

Comment: если вызывать фреймы по отдельности, все работает исправно... уже два часа бьюсь...

Comment: выложить полный код на pastebin можете?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/q2aS0paD

Comment: `"уже два часа бьюсь..."` - без [__воспроизводимых__ примеров данных](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7061/211923) никто за вас часами биться не захочет. ;)